# How do we communicate with contract functionality which is deployed in public test network using web3j

Tags: solidity, tokens, myetherwallet, ropsten, web3j

I would like to write a wepapp for security token contract which is deployed in public Ropsten Test Network using web3j. Need some idea.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you can find the easiest way here https://docs.web3j.io/smart_contracts.html, a java class will be generated for you and you can use it easily like any java class

Comment: please check the documentation before asking questions

Comment: ya sure..Referred this link https://docs.web3j.io/infura.html its worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello welcome to SO community.

web3.js documentation:
https://web3j.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Few things:

Sample code: A simple browser side implementation : [GitHub](https://github.com/web3j/examples)

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Can we use web3j (java) instead of web3js.

Comment: I have already created a webapp in ethereum private network using web3j +springboot by passing  wallet credentials and contract address. Now i want to communicate with public network. Will you share any reference link for this..

Comment: Oops.. sorry I misunderstood.. let me edit the answer and find some resources for yaa.. thank you

Comment: Thanks for the idea .i referred your GitHub code.It actually helped for me.I found a solution for this. I used infura API(Ropsten testnet), it will allow developer to communicate with testnetwork using web3j... Thank you